# Make div with relative postioning to overlap others

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some dives with relative postioning. I need one of them to overlap others on click. My solution is to set width of others div to 0 px and make them hidden. Are there any more elegant decisions?

Comment: and what is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/MryRA/

HTML

```
<div class="click"></div>
<div class="hide"></div>
<div class="hide"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    z-index:2;
}
div:nth-of-type(2) {
    background:blue;
    z-index:1;
}
div:nth-of-type(3) {
    background:green;
    z-index:1;
}
.marg_tp {
    margin-top:-50px;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var flag = true;
$(".click").on('click', function () {
    if (flag) {
        flag = false;
        $(".hide").addClass("marg_tp");
    } else {
        flag = true;
        $(".hide").removeClass("marg_tp");
    }
});
});
```